# PHP, AJAX, and server-client frustrations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that's generated from php.  The way I've done this is probably not the most efficient way to do it since I wrote it all myself and I'm not an expert.

Everything starts when the user pastes part numbers into a search box on a previous page, which is then sent here to return.php under the variable `lines`.

**return.php**

```
$c = $_POST['c'];
if (!$_SESSION['lines']) {
  $_SESSION['lines'] = $_POST['lines'];
}
$partNumber = array(); //define $partNumber as array

$x = -1;
$supplierQuery      = "SELECT distinct supplier, quotePartNumber FROM allparts WHERE quotePartNumber = '$q'" ;
$supplierResult     = mysqli_query($con, $supplierQuery);

foreach ($_SESSION['lines'] as $q) {
 $x = $x + 1; // each time we loop through this, x++

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($supplierResult)) {
     $partNumber[]   = $row['quotePartNumber'];
     $customerQuery  = "SELECT DISTINCT quoteCustomer FROM $supplier where quotePartNumber = '$q'";

    if (!$c) { // $c becomes set once a user types in an end customer - without that, we want ALL generic info to be returned.
        $costQuery      = "SELECT * FROM $supplier where quotePartNumber = '$partNumber[$x]' ORDER BY quoteCost ASC LIMIT 1" ;
      } else {            
        $costQuery      = "SELECT * FROM $supplier where quotePartNumber = '$partNumber[$x]' and quoteCustomer = '$c' ORDER BY quoteCost ASC LIMIT 1" ;
       }
       $getCustomer      = mysqli_query($con, $customerQuery);
    }
```

**later on in my table, I have this:**

```
<td><?= $partNumber[$x] ?></td>
<td><?= $cost ?></td>
<td>
  <select class="btn btn-danger" onChange="selectCustomerCMR(this.value)">
  <option value="" disabled selected><?php if($c) { print $c; } else { print "Select Purchasing Customer";} ?></option>                  

  <?php                              
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getCustomer)) {                                 

  $customerName = $row['quoteCustomer'];          
  ?>
    <option><?= $customerName ?></option>                        

  <?php
  }
  ?>          
  </select>    
</td>
```

**Any change to the dropdown will launch this script:**

```
<script>
function selectCustomerCMR(str) {
var id = str;

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'return.php',
      data: {'c':id,'lines':lines},        
        success:function(data){
        $("#info").html(data);
        }
  });        
}
</script>
```

## What I'm trying to do

Let's say my generated table has 3 rows, with part numbers
[image]

There is a drop-down to allow the user to select a specific customer.  When the user clicks on this, the script takes that value and uses AJAX to send it back to the same page (return.php), which then grabs it using the `$c = $_POST['c'];` code.

## My Issue

When return.php loads a "second time" with a value for `$c`, I don't know how to make it so that **the line that the user selected gets changed**.  Right now, anytime I select a customer from a line's drop-down, return.php reloads, and it assigns that customer to the FIRST row, ignoring all the other rows.

I specifically created `$partNumber` as an array and used `$x` so I could increase the value of x each time the `foreach` loop iterated.  This worked, so of the three lines in the above table, the first one is `$partNumber[0]` and the second one is `$partNumber[1]`, etc...  *But I don't know how to get that information into the javascript function and send it back to the page when it reloads, so that I can then change my SQL query to ONLY action when the condition is right for that line...*

Thanks for reading, and thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're using AJAX why would you reload the page?

Comment: I don't know, because this is the way I learned how to use AJAX?  Am I doing it incorrectly?  when return.php loads the first time, `$c` is not set.  It becomes set when someone selects a customer and AJAX reloads the page and sends that customer back in its POST call.  I don't know any other way to accomplish this other than by doing what I'm doing.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I am aware of that.  It's okay for now - I'll be changing the SQL queries before I go into production... I took the queries from a test database I wrote for myself.  I should have written them correctly in the first place, but I didn't, and making the system functional is more important to me right now.

Comment: You are missing the whole point of Ajax, which is in your case : getting the data when the `<select>` value change without reloading the page.

Comment: K, so how would I modify the AJAX query to make it better?

Comment: What element is `#info`?  Is that the table?

Comment: `#info` is a DIV on the home page, Return.php is loaded into this DIV when the user first pastes text into the textbox and that data is brought over.  So I'm basically reloading return.php into the div a second time - but this time, with `$c` populated.

Comment: I'm confused, if you can post a live demo or something it will be more easier.

Comment: not sure how I'd do that.... it's on an internal server, and jsfiddle isn't really useful in this situation since I can't incorporate PHP into it.  The main issue here is that once the script loads, I don't know how to get info on a specific line into that script, so that I can pass it BACK to the page when I reload it.  So - if I'm selecting a customer for line 2, how do I get the value of `$x` into the script?

Comment: If your PHP is just outputting HTML, why do you need to know which row to update?  Won't they all be updated?

Comment: Yes, but I need ONLY the line where the user changes the customer to be updated, because there's no duplication of customers in the system.  If I select "ACME" on the first drop-down, ACME only has pricing on that first part, so I only want line 1 to "refresh."  Then I select "DISNEY" for line 2, and I only want line 2 to refresh, but line 1 to keep "ACME", as DISNEY has no pricing for line 1, and ACME has no pricing for line 2... etc... does that make sense?

Comment: I would suggest an alternative approach, then.  When you're refreshing an individual row, have `return.php` return a JSON object with just the data for that row, and update the values in your JavaScript.

Comment: that is exactly what I want to do - return data from the entire row - but I don't know how to do that.  In any given "row" on the physical table that the user sees, the part number that is populated by `$partNumber[x]` links to the customer drop-down, but when the user selects a customer name from the drop-down, I don't know how to get that `[x]` value to be sent ALONG with the `<select>` value.... If I could figure that out, I'd be golden.

Comment: You could set a custom data attribute such as `data-x` or something like that on the `<select>`.  Then you could change your onchange handler to pass `this` (the select) instead of `this.value`.  That way, you can get `id` from `select.value` and `x` from `select.getAttribute("data-x")`.

Comment: yes - that makes perfect sense.  I had thought about submitting `this` instead of `this.value`, but I don't know how to modify the `<select>` code to include `data-x`.  How and where would I physically put that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing your `<select>` code to this:

```
<select class="btn btn-danger" data-x="<?= $x ?>" onChange="selectCustomerCMR(this)">
```

Then, your Ajax code can be changed to this:

```
function selectCustomerCMR(select) {
    var id = select.value, x = select.getAttribute("data-x");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'return.php',
        data: { c: id, lines: lines, x: x },        
        success: function(data){
            // Update!
        }
    });        
}
```

That way, your PHP can get both `c` and `x`.

Comment: dude I love you.  This is a great solution, and let's me get both variables back.  I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest of what needs to happen now :)  Thank you!